# Optimize a deep and map function in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

Given the following Map:

```
const myMap = new Map([
    [“a”, [{
        files: [{
            name: “f1a”
        }, {
            name: “f2a”
        }]
    }]],
    [“b”, [{
        files: [{
            name: “f1b”
        }, {
            name: “f2b”
        }]
    }]]
]);
```

I need to have the following result:

```
[{
    "name": "f1a"
}, {
    "name": "f2a"
}, {
    "name": "f1b"
}, {
    "name": "f2b"
}]
```

I achieved that using:

```
[...x.values()].flat().map(x => x.files).flat()
```

How can the above be optimized, can even use lodash I don't mind.

I tried to use lodash: flattenMapDeep

but didn't work

Comment: Looks reasonable to me

Comment: Yeah, however, I found a bit complex for other devs to look at it, was thinking of using flattenMapDeep, or MapValues, or something like that... from lodash

Comment: `[...myMap.values()].flat().flatMap(x => x.files)`

Comment: Logically, your solution is the most readable and understandable piece to achieve the task. Other than the last part where `map` is followed by `flat` calls, it could be clubbed into a `flatMap` call. AFA, other devs and their complexity in understanding it stems, it is certainly with what `Map#values()`, `Array#flat`, and similar APIs do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#[flat, flatMap]`:

```js
const myMap = new Map([
  ['a', [{
    files: [{
      name: 'f1a'
    }, {
      name: 'f2a'
    }]
  }]],
  ['b', [{
    files: [{
      name: 'f1b'
    }, {
      name: 'f2b'
    }]
  }]]
])

// Your code.. 
const result1 = [...myMap.values()].flat().map(x => x.files).flat()
console.log('Result1', result1)

// Using Array#[flat, flatMap] (((Fastest)))
const result2 = [...myMap.values()].flat().flatMap(x => x.files)
console.log('Result2', result2)
```